Python Pip requirements.txt - enforce installation of selected package before others
Hello I have a Python project which requires python package onnxsim, which doesn't work without python package cmake (cmake from Ubuntu repo is too old).
I wanted to have a single requirements.txt file defining these requirements:
cmake
onnxsim

But when I wanted to use it I got error: AssertionError: Could not find "cmake" executable!, because cmake was not installed yet when pip tried to install onnxsim.
Also installing them together using command doesn't work pip install cmake onnxsim
Only workaround was installing cmake using separate command
pip install cmake
pip install onnxsim

How to enforce full installation of cmake package before installing other packages in requirements.txt ?

For easy reproduction I suggest using Docker docker container run --rm -it --entrypoint bash python

Why would I run a docker container (and it's not even specified which container) when a virtual environment can do for reproduction?

Are you sure it's the Python package cmake, and not the tool CMake?

Afaik, the installation order of a requirements file is the one listed in the file. I just ran that two-line requirements file in a v-env, and it worked totally fine.

I looked it up on PyPI: so the Python 'cmake' package will install the cmake executable (and friends). Perhaps then the docker container makes a bit more sense, since I already have a cmake installed on my system, so that's already found when installing the packages. Still installs fine when I remove the system cmake, though!


Why would I run a docker container
-- This is part of big and a bit convoluted environment using not only Python



Are you sure it's the Python package cmake, and not the tool CMake?
-- It is a tool cmake, which can be installed either with apt or with pip, but apt provides outdated version


I don't think this works: onnxsim depends on cmake, but how that's installed, is external to onnxsim, Python or pip. So it's up to the user to provide a valid cmake installation (and probably a C/C++ compiler asa well). So there's always two steps: set up the environment with a valid cmake, and then install the package with its dependencies. (If you were using e.g. Conda, then you can combine it into a single Conda package.)

onnxsim should probably list cmake as one of its own build dependencies, rather than making you specify it. But then you might be installing an unnecessary version of cmake if you already have it outside the Python ecosystem. One solution would be for the upstream to provide a Python wheel which already has the non-Python requirements compiled and ready to use. Another would be to use a language-agnostic tool like Nix to build and install the package.

Why not just download a more current version of CMake from https://cmake.org/download/ ? Package managers aren't the final say on what software you can have on your system. Could be as simple as something like curl https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.30.5/cmake-3.30.5-linux-x86_64.sh | /bin/sh

You can use
sed 's/#.*//' requirements.txt | grep -v '^$' | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install

It will firstly remove comments by sed command, then removes empty lines with grep, and then take each line from the requirements.txt file and apply pip install command to it. It works like two separate commands

It works only with simple requirements.txt files for example file containing comment like #test packages breaks pip ERROR: Invalid requirement: '#test packages'

cat requirements.txt | xargs echo pip install -> pip install package1 packag2 etc… It seems xargs runs the commnd once for all packages. To run one by one there should be an option…

For a more general requirements file: will this work with the -r and -c options. Requirements files seem to be more flexible than can be practical: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/

@pktiuk  added sed and grep pipe to remove the comments

You may want to answer at the suggested duplicate instead; it'll be useful there for future visitors. (This answer actually combines several answers to the duplicate.)
